# Pentaho insert operation error due to a collation

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, utf-8, pentaho, etl

I have a Pentaho transformation which executes a procedure from a database and then insert the rows into another database.

The source database is a sql server 2008 r2 database, not utf8 charset, Latin_general_ci, and the destiny databanase is postgresql with utf8 charset.

If I execute the ETL it throws an error when attempt to insert the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO aux (name, account, id,  state) VALUES ( 'UAN 5 BAR    ','01082082R','UY903847JDNF','BAJA')
```

As you can see in the name value field exists some unknown characters. Pentaho shows that with some square images,exactly 6. If I copy the insert statement from log the row is break in this point so I understant that it is a break of line or something like that.

I solved this for other rows, that the hidden chars are different, but in this case I can not solve this. Furthermore I would like to find a solution to solve all the possible problems of charset.

Anyone knows how to solve that?

In the other hidden char I solved it applying `cast(name as binary)` but this does not workd for this other case.

EDIT

The value `'UAN 5 BAR    '` has unknown chars just after the word BAR until the quote char '.
When I say unknown means weird chars that I can not see what they are.

Comment: I don't see unknow characters, please update question with exact error you get

Comment: @VaoTsun Questione edited

Comment: Please provide more information about aux table to which database it belongs and it's definition (i'm interesting in column types). You write about 2 databases, but your query does not affect both of them